# ST_Contains gives geometry collection error where there are none

Tags: database, geometry, amazon-redshift, postgis

I am writing a query in Redshift to return records where the point geometries from a table are contained within a polygon defined in the query. The expected result is a subset of the ~60000 records that are geographically located within the polygon.

The view contains only ST_POINT geometries and the containing polygon is an ST_POLYGON and none are geometry collections, so using ST_CONTAINS is the usual approach (but this is not working).

To achieve my goal, the query that I'm using is:

```
SELECT  
    vw.site_id, vw.name, vw.geom_wgs84
FROM   
    vw_bh_collars vw  
WHERE   
     St_Contains(  
        ST_GeomFromEWKT(  
                        'SRID=4326;POLYGON((143.001844 -15.767258,144.392028 -16.721939,142.575232 -19.770531,140.400021 -17.999052,143.001844 -15.767258))'  
                        )  
        , vw.geom_wgs84)  
;
```

The problem is that I am getting an unexpected error.:

error:  Pyxis exception
code:      23002
context:   contains is not defined for geometry collections

however, as you can see from the below code, none of the involved geometries appear to be collections:

```
   SELECT  
    DISTINCT(ST_IsCollection(vw.geom_wgs84)),  
    ST_IsCollection(ST_GeomFromEWKT 
    (  
    'SRID=4326;POLYGON((143.001844 -15.767258,144.392028 -16.721939,142.575232 -19.770531,140.400021 -17.999052,143.001844 -15.767258))'  
    ))  
FROM 
    vw_bh_collars vw
```

Result:
| st_iscollection | st_iscollection |
| ----------------- | -----------------|
| false | false |

The geoms are valid and non-empty postgis geoms and the polygon is closed.
I am struggling to understand the source of this error or where to go next.

Help please.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).